# rt_SATURATE Macro definition in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, macros, clamp

Anyone knows below macro? I googled it but cant find anything useful.  What does it do?

```
#define rt_SATURATE(sig,ll,ul) (((sig) >= (ul)) ? (ul) : (((sig) <= (ll)) ? (ll) : (sig)) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does what [std::clamp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) does.

It "returns" `sig` restricted to a range given by `ll` (lower limit) and `ul` (upper limit).

As the question is tagged with [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) another alternative doing the same thing but with different order to the parameters is [qBound](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qBound)